# How many solutions to $a^n-b^n=2^{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Are there a distinct number of solutions to:

$a^n-b^n=2^{100}$

If a, b and n are positive integers greater than 1

I have tried to solve it with code but it takes to long.

```
 for ($a=3; $a -lt 5000; $a++) {
    for ($b=2; $b -lt $a; $b++){
        for ($n=2; $n -lt 200; $n++) {
            $x=[bigint]::Pow($a,$n)-[bigint]::Pow($b,$n)
            if ( [bigint]::Pow(2,100) -eq $x) {write-host $a,$b,$n}
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Try `elementary-number-theory`. What have you tried? Factoring $a^n - b^n$ *could* be a good start.

Comment: @curios It probably takes too long because using shell to program something that is numerically intensive is a very bad idea. Try a real programming language. In my computer, a simple  "for" cycle takes about 300 times more in the shell than in a real programming language.

Answer (score 0):

It has exactly $49$ solutions for $n=2$ given by $a = 2^{99-k}+2^{k-1}$, $b = 2^{99-k}-2^{k-1}$ with $k = 1, 2, \ldots, 49$.

For $n>2$ it has no solutions.

Hints for the proof:
Reduce to the case where $n$ is an odd prime or a power of $2$.